# iPhone : Photos framework : how to get only those album/images which created by my app only not by others?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, photosframework

I am creating a application like photos app. My application creates albums and captures images and  saves them in albums in photos app. For this I am using Photos framework. When i am fetching albums it gives me albums which created by my app as well as other apps. So I want only those album/images which created by my app only not by other apps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight-forward way to do this. But this is a workaround.

```
PHFetchResult *topLevelUserCollections = [PHCollectionList fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions:nil];
    self.collectionsFetchResults = @[topLevelUserCollections];

    for (PHFetchResult *fetchResult in self.collectionsFetchResults) {
            for (PHAssetCollection *assetCollection in fetchResult) {
                BOOL shouldShowCollection = NO;
                if ([assetCollection.localizedTitle isEqualToString:@"YOUR_APP_NAME"]) {
                    shouldShowCollection = YES;
                }

                if (shouldShowCollection) {
                   //collectionsToShow are the collections that you will show up in your table view
                   [self.collectionsToShow addObject:assetCollection];
                }
            }
        }
```