# How can I show only one album which is created on my app in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I want to show users only picture/video taken in my app on camera roll.
So, when user click gallery button, my app only show "my app" album.
Is this possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch all images from custom Photo Album - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169185/how-to-fetch-all-images-from-custom-photo-album-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing

When you save your picture captured by your camera, you can save then specific folder like "AppName-Photos" so each photos save in that particuler folder and when you retrive album just take only photos when there is album name "AppName-Photos" and ignore others

To save photos to your own custom album you can refer this link : [iOS save photo in an app specific album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972185/ios-save-photo-in-an-app-specific-album)

To Fetch only custom album photos you can refer this link: [iPhone : Photos framework : how to get only those album/images which created by my app only not by others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987198/iphone-photos-framework-how-to-get-only-those-album-images-which-created-by)